# How to get the base alphabet of a foreign word and sort them accordingly like in device local contact?

Tags: android, sorting, locale, android-contacts

For example, let's say that a local contact have multiple Japanese contacts with the name たなか, つなき, and てるてる. In the local contact these names will be sorted under the section index letter た.

For what I've read, it is possible to sort them via collate, but how do you sort them to index た or even know that they should go to the た index?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API has a trick for returning that list of alphabet letters, and optionally also including counts per character.

See official docs for `EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX`:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX

Example code:

```
Uri uri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
          .appendQueryParameter(Contacts.EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX, "true")
          .build();
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
          new String[] {Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
          null, null, null);
 Bundle bundle = cursor.getExtras();
 if (bundle.containsKey(Contacts.EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX_TITLES) && bundle.containsKey(Contacts.EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX_COUNTS)) {
     String sections[] = bundle.getStringArray(Contacts.EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX_TITLES);         
     // sections will now contain an array of characters that represent the first letter of each available contact name
     // optionally - if you need counts per letter - int counts[] = bundle.getIntArray(Contacts.EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX_COUNTS);
 }
```